# How to tell if the MicrosoftAjax javascript library is not being used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, javascript

I've got the following scripts in an MVC3 application, but I'm thinking that they aren't being used, just referenced. Is there an easy way to tell if they are being used somewhere within the markup?

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Everything I've seen so far ajax wise is using the included jQuery libraries. I've already checked for html.BeingAjaxForm and found nothing, so I really have no idea what else could be hiding out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, Third Edition"

> There are also a set of files in the '*~/Scripts*' folder whose names start with *Microsoft*, for example MicrosoftAjax.js
>
> These are from version 2 of the MVC framework and predate Microsoft fully embracing jQuery in ASP.NET MVC. We don't discuss these files since they have been superseded and are included in MVC framework just for compatibillity with earlier versions.

Since the book was written by Adam Freeman & Steven Sanderson (and the later works for Microsoft) then I think that's good enough for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to tell that they are not being used is to remove all references to them, then thoroughly test all client-side functionality.

Most likely... unless your app was upgraded from MVC2 or someone added some code using the MS scripts noted, they are not needed for your MVC3 site.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts that you have listed are required for a backward compatibility with MVC 2 applications.

As your question is regarding MVC 3 application, removing these scripts will have no effect on your application.

Comment: Deleting those MS Ajax files will *not* break unobtrusive validation in MVC3. See Skuld's answer. They are there only for compatability with upgraded MVC2 projects.

Comment: Well, now your answer does not relate to the question, which was specifically about MVC3. Your question seems to suggest that removing those scripts will cause some sort of "silent failure", with the text you have quoted.

Comment: Scripts that Chris has listed are used by MVC 2, if you remove them, validation will fail silently. This implies that it won't affect MVC 3 app, I'm sorry if you are thick and can't work this out. I love people that waste their own time trying to pick something out,when all I'm trying to do is help as well as learn. So yep, +1 for wasting time, rather than helping with structured criticism :D

Comment: I am trying to help you improve your answer, which is very confusing.

Comment: Okie, then I do apologise and I'll edit it shortly :) This is not my first language and have about a year of development experience =)